# Cannot run gulp, or other npm commands, from local npm install on Windows

Tags: npm, gulp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having problems running `gulp`, and other npm installed commands from the local `node_modules` path.

For example I'll have a script `sass` that calls `gulp sass` and invoke `npm run  sass`, and it claims the `gulp` binary isn't found (`'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`) -> but it's definitely there, in `node_modules/bin`.

A global install of `gulp` does work, but that's not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a [so-called cursed](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3356) WSL directory with `setCaseSensitiveInfo` set to true, coupled with the default `PATHEXT` which contains all CAPS extensions. So when you try to run `gulp` it looks for `gulp.CMD` but the distributed command is `gulp.cmd`.

Adding lowercase variants to `PATHEXT` appears to have fixed it without having to frob `setCaseSensitiveInfo` to false everywhere.